# Why is $A$ on the left hand side yet $B$ is on the right hand side when we evaluate $ \frac{d}{dt}(e^{tA}Ce^{tB}) = Ae^{tA}Ce^{tB} + e^{tA}Ce^{tB}B$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, exponential-function, banach-spaces

I came across the following expression where $A:Y\to Y$, $B:X\to X$, and $C:X\to Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ being Banach spaces:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(e^{tA}Ce^{tB}) = Ae^{tA}Ce^{tB} + e^{tA}Ce^{tB}B.
$$

So we have the product rule followed by the chain rule. Regarding the expression on the right hand side, why is $A$ on the left hand side in the first expression, yet $B$ is on the right hand side in the second expression?

Comment: $B$ is on the right, for the same reason as $A$ is on the left.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you might write the second term as $ \mathrm e^{tA}CB\mathrm e^{tB}$, but I guess it's for symmetry reasons. Don't forget  $B$ and $\mathrm e^{tB}$ commute.

Comment: Why do they commute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For no special reason. $e^A$ and $A$ commute for any matrix $A$.

In any case, $B$ should be to the right of $C$.

Comment: Why do they commute?

Comment: $$A\,e^A=A\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^{n+1}}{n!}=e^A\,A.$$